# Error getting the string between two patterns

Tags: grep, search

I want to get a string between two patterns. The pattern is the first environment `<p> </p>` in an html file.

```
<p>Sorcery, 
          R (1)
          </p>
        <p class="ctext"><b>As an additional cost to cast Goblin Grenade, sacrifice a Goblin.<br><br>Goblin Grenade deals 5 damage to target creature or player.</b></p>


      <p><i>Don't underestimate the aerodynamic qualities of the common goblin.</i></p>
      <p>Illus. Kev Walker</p>
```

That environment is the first of the file so I discard everything matched until the `<p>` and I want to delete everything after the `</p>`.

```
name="goblin grenade"
wget -O- http://magiccards.info/query?q="$name" | grep -oP '<p>\K[^<]+'
```

I don't know why it doesn't work properly. I get

```
Sorcery, 
Illus. Kev Walker
```

Comment: According to your question and example text, the expected output would be `Sorcery,\nR (1)\n`: that doesn't match what you expect: please clarify.

Comment: Instead of Searching inline, and stripping after, strip before with `sed -E 's/<[^>]*>//g' <<<$output_text`, where `output_text` is a new empty file.  Then grep the file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't parse HTML with regex, instead, use a proper HTML parser.

#### theory :

According to the compiling theory, HTML can't be parsed using regex based on [finite state machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite-state_machine). Due to hierarchical construction of HTML you need to use a [pushdown automaton](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pushdown_automaton) and manipulate [LALR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LR_parser) grammar using tool like [YACC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yacc).

#### realLife©®™ everyday tool :

instead, you should using a correct tool for a correct job.

...and it's a job for [xmllint](/questions/tagged/xmllint) :

by *string matching* :

```
string="Sorcery"
xmllint --html --xpath "//p[contains(text(), '$string')]/text()" file_or_URL
```

by the Nth `<p>` node where N is 1 here :

```
xmllint --html --xpath "//p[1]/text()" file_or_URL
```

Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Whoot! That's better than my idea... +1  Can `file_or_URL` contain a parameter tho?

Comment: Woot woot eyoung100 =) Which parameter did you expect ?

Comment: Look at the OP's post, that's a parameter query: `query?q="$name"`

Comment: Could you explain this argument? `'//p[contains(text(), "Sorcery")]/text()'` I think you are using the string that I want to search as the pattern, but that won't be always the same.

Comment: I don't know what is inside the <p> </p> environment. In this case is sorcery but it may be something else. That's why I want to search that string.

Comment: So what is there instead of something else ? If you dunno, then the Xpath should be : `//p` or `//p[1]` for ths first match

Comment: Can I get the content of //p[1] in just one line?

Comment: What's wrong with `xmllint --html --xpath "//p[1]/text()" file_or_URL` ?

Comment: just one line of output or one line of command-line ?

Comment: One line of output. I did `xmllint --html --xpath "//p[1]/text()" name >name2; rm name; tr -d '\n' <name2 > name; rm name2`. I still don't understand the html parsing how can I learn about this?

Comment: `xmllint --html --xpath "//p[1]/text()" file_or_URL | tr -d "\n"` Search google about XPath to learn

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer:

@sputnick answer is clearly the right way to go. (I love xmllint and i use it for several XML/HTML tasks; thank you for teaching me about xpath option!!)

Nevertheless other less robust techniques can also be useful in
disposable scripting...

Getting the first paragraph with regex (in Perl)

```
perl -n0e 'm!<p.*?>(.*?)</p>!s   and print $1'
```

or if you want to remove '`\n`'

```
perl -n0e 'm!<p.*?>(.*?)</p>!s   and print $1 =~ s/\n//gr'
```